# Assigning value to a django form after form have been initiated

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form     SOproduct2Form

in this form I have a field priceperunit

It is defined in my model like this

```
priceperunit =  MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
```

I am trying after the form got initialized to assign it  with default value .
Since form is object and not dictionary I do it like this

```
form = SOproduct2Form(instance = soproduct1)
#form.priceperunit = 3
form.priceperunit = soproduct1.product.defaultPrice
#setattr(form, priceperunite, 5)
```

I am not getting any error,at the output it always displays 0

I tried to play with assigning value directly I am getting same 0.(see commented line)
When use setattr (also commented) I am getting error that priceperunit is not defined.

Question: What is the problem and how to make it work?

Comment: Why do you want to do this after it is initialized? Why not pass it in in the `initial` dict, or by modifying the instance?

Comment: Yes it is great idea and it actually works :)

   soproduct1.priceperunit = soproduct1.product.defaultPrice
        form = SOproduct2Form(instance = soproduct1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to assign the value AFTER the form is initiated? According to your problem description, it seems to me that you just want to set the initial value entered in the field.

Generally in standard Django fields you would use `initial` argument, but I checked the source code of `django-money` and it seems you need `default` and `default_currency` arguments. Try something like this:

`priceperunit = MoneyField(default=value, default_currency=currency)`

Comment: yes it is good idea to do it before the initiated as you and Daniel mentioned.

I assign default dynamically since each product has default price